# Is it possible to create and trigger email alerts for APIs in Sterling Order Management system?

Tags: ibm-sterling

Is there a way to create Email Alerts in Sterling Order management system when a Specific API is inactive/no activity for a brief period of time? For example,If a custom API which reads/grabs messages from one queue and places in another queue every 10 mins goes inactive or there is no activity recorded, can an email alert be fired by the sterling OMS product?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge , its not possible in Sterling OMS currently. If the intention is to monitor Integration Server and get an alert when messages are not consumed from a queue , an alert can be created on MQ manager. MQ manager monitoring can be done to trigger an alert when queue depth increase beyond a threshold or Last message in queue is not consumed within pre-configured interval of time.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by running health monitor agents in Sterling OMS. The Health Monitor agent can be configured to alert system administrators when problems occur such as when an application server crashes or agent servers are not processing tasks.

To configure the health monitor agent, follow the below steps -
From the Application Platform tree, choose System Administration > Health Monitor Rules. The Health Monitor Rules window displays in the work area.
Select the applicable option from the list.

To run the Health Monitor Agent, run the startHealthMonitor.sh/cmd script file located in your /bin directory